# Whats the point of `beforeunload` returnValue if the message does not get set?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, listener, onbeforeunload

**TL;DR No modern browsers use the message.**

**You can abuse the api with this message so browsers dropped the use of the parameter. Thank you Huangism, lilezek, and James for the below responses.**

What is the point of setting the event returnValue in the `onbeforeunload` callback if the message never gets set?

[The MDN docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) recommend that we set this value, and I'm not able to prompt the user without setting this value. However when setting that value I don't see my string in any of the confirmation messages.

[Example of chrome dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEJzE.png)

Comment: It used to work in older browsers but modern browsers now do not show the text anymore which I assume is to be more secure?

Comment: It was removed because this technique was often used by disreputable sites to scam users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload):

> In some browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog.

Also, at the end of the MDN documentation, there is a table that shows every browser removed support of custom text.

Comment: None of the modern browsers shows that text anymore

Comment: @Huangism idk about 2017 but I'm testing it now and can clearly see this message.